# Change sub-menu position of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm adding an additional taxonomy to the Posts post-type and would like it to appear between Categories and Tags in the control panel Posts sub-menu. I know when registering custom post types you can set the control panel menu position via the `menu_position` argument, but I can't find anything similar for custom taxonomies - they just seem to be added to the bottom of the list.

Anyone know of a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unluckily does not exist a clean way to do this, because register taxonomy doesn't provide a `menu_order` argument.

But you can act on global `$submenu` variable and reorder it, something like

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
  global $submenu;
  $found = FALSE;
  $before = $after = array();
  $tax_slug = 'my_custom_tax'; // change your taxonomy name here
  foreach ( $submenu['edit.php'] as $item ) {
    if ( ! $found || $item[2] === 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $tax_slug ) {
      $before[] = $item;
    } else {
      $after[] = $item;
    }
    if( $item[2] === 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category' ) $found = TRUE;
  }
  $submenu['edit.php'] = array_values( array_merge( $before, $after ) );
}, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a plugin but I appreciate the answer.  Good to know I wasn't going crazy looking for a clean way to handle it. :)